# Sqlalchemy - how to get an object, and filter which rows in the child class

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I’m new to Sqlalchemy, and in need of some help.

i have a model, with a one to many relation:

```
class Metnadev(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'metnadev'

    #personal info
    id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(Unicode(255))
    last_name = Column(Unicode(255))
    birth_day = Column(Date)
    activitys = relationship("Activity", backref="metnadev")

class Activity(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'activity'

    id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    metnadev_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('metnadev.id'))

    location = Column(Unicode(255))
    visible = Column(Boolean,default=True)
```

When I do

```
metnadev = DBSession.query(Metnadev).filter_by(id=kw['id']).one()
```

I get the object, with the child, great.
I want to get the object, but only get the rows from the child class, where **visible == True**

I searched but I’m not sure how to do it,
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This section of the documentation has your answer: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_6/orm/relationships.html#building-query-enabled-properties

```
class Metnadev(DeclarativeBase):
    #...
    @property
    def activities(self):
        return object_session(self).query(Activity).filter_by(visible=True).with_parent(self).all()
```

Comment: Thanks, after adding that property to the object, i can now get the filtered list in: **metnadev.activites**

Comment: fresh link http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#building-query-enabled-properties

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple ways you can do this.

For a one-off, you can just run a second query:

```
from sqlalchemy import and_

activities = Activity.query.filter(and_(Activity.metnadev_id == kw['id'], Activity.visible==True)).all()
```

You can change the relationship so only visible items are returned:

```
activities = relationship("Activity",
               primaryjoin="and_(Activity.metnadev_id==Metnadev.id, "
               "Activity.visible==True)")
```

If you need more control you can join the tables, but it sounds like the relationship configuration would work for you. Let me know if that's not the case.

Hope that helps!